# Flexbox assistance

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Im currently practicing Flexbox and trying to make this layout on my website, it has two images (1 vertical and 1 horizontal) and a block of text, I want it to look like the image but cant seem to find a solution

[Container image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yW9ld.jpg)

Comment: Flexbox layouts are better for flow presentation. Grid might be a better method for your desired presentation.  Any adversions to the grid layout or are you just practicing only to use the flexbox design.

Comment: I know this isn't the question, but you could use bootstrap in these situations. It really makes stuff easy. Checkout bootstrap grid system.

Comment: @jmrker sounds good, im currently just self teaching my self for web development, ill look into grid layout to see if that works!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comments that CSS grid would be more suited to creating grid layouts. However in an effort to answer your question, please see an example using Flexbox below.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
}

.left {
  background-color: #aaa;
  flex: 1;
}

.right {
  display: flex;
  flex: 2;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.top {
  background-color: #bbb;
  flex: 1;
}

.bottom {
  background-color: #ccc;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left"></div>
  
  <div class="right">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ur my hero THANKS!!